# Update command of MySQL not working in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, xampp

This is my first very simple learning php program I have connected my PHP with MySQL Server and the Insert, Delete is working great but Update has some issue. When I press the update button nothing happens.
My database name is ddb3, the table name is student1.
The Apache server I am using is hosted via Xampp.
`mysql_error();` shows no error and also no error in apache logfile

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("ddb3");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO student1(name, age) VALUES ('$name', '$age');");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM student1 WHERE name = '$name';");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE student1 SET name = '$name' WHERE age = '$age';");
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <center>
            <form name='f1' action='prog3.php' method='post'>
                <b>Name:<b><input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br>
                <b>Age:<b><input type="text" name="age" size="5"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert to Table"/>
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete from Table"/>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Row"/>
            </form>
        </center>
        <?php
            echo "<table align='center' name='t1' border='1' width=500px>
                  <tr><th>NAME</th><th>AGE</th></tr>";
            $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student1");
            while($colmn = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
                echo "<tr><td>$colmn[0]</td><td>$colmn[1]</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "<table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Also use prepared statments to prevent sql injection

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to find out if you get an error or print out the statement and try it in a sql client, maybe the values have not the value which you expect

Comment: @Jens tried mysql_error(); but no errors were found. I am using Xampp server

Answer (score 1):

Describing the observed behavior as "not working" or "nothing happens" gives very little useful information, in determining *what* the actual problem is.

(How are you making the determination that "nothing happens", or that it's "not working"?)

I suggest adding some debugging output (for example, an echo or var_dump) at particular points in the code, to determine which path in the code is being taken.  (Is `$_POST['update']` set? Is the `if` condition evaluating to TRUE?)

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

I will note that it's very strange that we would change the `name` of a `student` based on `age`.  For example, this statement will attempt to assign the same name to every student that is a particular age ...

```
UPDATE student1
   SET name = 'Ted'
  WHERE age = '19'
```

It would be very odd to do this. The SQL is valid. What is strange is *which* rows are being changed (all rows that have age=19), and the change that is being applied (changing the name of all the rows to the same value.)

It doesn't matter if the student's name is Jack, or Jill, or whatever. *Every* row in the table that has an age value of 19 is going to changed.

---

We typically don't store "age" as a column, but instead store a date of birth (dob). The DOB won't change. But age is going to change; age is the difference between DOB and the current (or some specified "as of") date. Age in years? Age in months, or days?

---

If we insist on storing age, then its much more likely that the `age` column is going to changed that the name column.

To identify *which* row should be updated... is `name` unique?  Can there be two or more rows with the same `name`?

We probably want some unique identifier for the student, and use that in an UPDATE statment.

```
UPDATE student1 s 
   SET s.some_col = 'new_value'
 WHERE s.id = 'unique_identifier'
```

---

Do *not* use the deprecated mysql_ interface for new development. Use PDO. (Or use mysqli_).

Also use prepared statements with bind placeholders to mitigate SQL Injection vulnerabilities. If for some unfathomable reason we can't do that, then at the very minimum, any potentially unsafe values incorporated into SQL text *must* be properly escaped.

Little Bobby Tables  https://xkcd.com/327/

OWASP Project SQL Injection  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet